# SharePoint Automated Email Follow up

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am looking to complete an email drip campaign that has a workflow that can send automated email response to prospects who have no affiliation to SharePoint, just have their contact email in a list. I know that you can send these automated templates replies using "Alerts" to internal people and even to people who have external user license using "Smart Alert Pro".

Although to my knowledge you cannot set up an email drip like this to someone who has not signed in their external user license. I do not want to sign up prospect's for external user's license, that is backwards.

So how can I automate the follow up lead emails pertaining to fields like "Created By" to  a non external user license email address's.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up a few things in there.  In SharePoint there is not an out of the box method for scheduling workflows.  You can for sure get creative with multiple lists and looping actions - but this set's you up for trouble in managing that type of solution.

You will either need to consider a custom solution - or look to a 3rd party tool, such as Nintex Workflow - which supports the actions you are looking for.